# Caching of Yahoo API data, permitted?

Tags: api, caching, yahoo

Just a quick query really. Is it against the TOS to cache data extracted from Yahoo? For example if I were to use the Yahoo Geocode API, and cached the location data every time a search was completed, essentially storing it in my database so that location was then permanently stored for the future use and I wouldn't have to use the Geocode data?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is against the ToS.

From the [terms of service](http://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/maps/mapsapi/mapsapi-2141.html):

> f. YOU SHALL NOT:
>   ...
>   (viii) store or allow end users to store map imagery, map data or geocoded location information from the Yahoo! Maps APIs for any future use;